# Remove an IObservable from merged sequence

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, system.reactive

I am using Observable.Merge to combine multiple sequences and display in a single view in UI. Users can choose to add or remove sequences(feeds) in the UI. While I have used Merge to combine feeds. I am not sure how I can detach an IObservable from a Merged sequence. Currently I am creating a brand new IObservable omitting the feeds I want to. Is it possible to dynamically add and remove to an IObsevable that the ViewModel has already subscribed to?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at using `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` and then use `Merge`. This automatically allows you to remove a sequence by ending the inner `IObservable<T>`. Simple.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would also work, but I suspect there are neater ways.

```
class Merger<T>
{
    Subject<T> _merged = new Subject<T>();

    public IObservable<T> Merged { get { return _merged; } }

    public IDisposable Add(IObservable<T> newStream)
    {
        return newStream.Subscribe(_merged);
    }
}
```

To remove something from the merged stream, dispose of the IDisposable.

Answer (score 0):

This might help get you started, but on reconnection, because b is cold, b will restart from the beginning:

```
var a = Observable.Generate('A', x => x <= Char.MaxValue, x => ++x, x => x, x => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)).Select(x => "a: " + x).Publish();
var b = Observable.Generate('a', x => x <= Char.MaxValue, x => ++x, x => x, x => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)).Select(x => "b: " + x).Publish();

var merged = a.Merge(b).Publish();
var submerged = merged.Subscribe(x => x.Dump());

var subA = a.Connect();
var subB = b.Connect();
merged.Connect();

Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(t => subB.Dump("Disposing b.").Dispose());
Task.Delay(4000).ContinueWith(t => b.Connect()).ContinueWith(_ => "Reconnected to b");
```

**EDIT:**

To add another 'c' to the merged IO:

```
var a = Observable.Generate('A', x => x <= Char.MaxValue, x => ++x, x => x, x => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)).Select(x => "a: " + x).Publish();
var b = Observable.Generate('a', x => x <= Char.MaxValue, x => ++x, x => x, x => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)).Select(x => "b: " + x).Publish();
var c = Observable.Generate('1', x => x <= Char.MaxValue, x => ++x, x => x, x => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)).Select(x => "c: " + x).Publish();

var merged = a.Merge(b).Merge(c).Publish();
var submerged = merged.Subscribe(x => x.Dump());

var subA = a.Connect();
var subB = b.Connect();
merged.Connect();

Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(t => subB.Dump("Disposing b.").Dispose());
Task.Delay(4000).ContinueWith(t => b.Connect()).ContinueWith(_ => "Reconnected to b".Dump());
Task.Delay(6000).ContinueWith(t => c.Connect()).ContinueWith(_ => "Connecting to c".Dump());
```

Comment: Lets say I have to add c to it on a command. Do I have to merge everything again and call connect on a,b,c and merged?

Comment: No, you can merge, and then connect to c whenever you want; I've updated the code to demonstrate it.  HTH. :)

Comment: Almost there. But I don't know the parameters of c upfront and it can run upto 100 different feeds. So can't have a merged upfront. Have to merge based on request.